# 2x beaglebone black microcontrolers and nrf24l01 connection doesn't work

Tags: linux, linux-device-driver, beagleboneblack

I'm trying to setup connection between two BBB using nrf24l01. 
I hope i set up everything properly( but I'm not really sure), I used this tutorial https://electron14.com/?p=404 and this code : RF24/librf24-bbb/librf24, and some self investigation.
the result of pingtest is :

```
./pingtest

RF24/examples/pingpair/
ROLE: Ping out
- gpio.cpp RF24::begin end fun
STATUS           = 0x0e RX_DR=0 TX_DS=0 MAX_RT=0 RX_P_NO=7 TX_FULL=0
RX_ADDR_P0-1     = 0xf0f0f0f0e1 0xf0f0f0f0d2
RX_ADDR_P2-5     = 0xc3 0xc4 0xc5 0xc6
TX_ADDR          = 0xf0f0f0f0e1
RX_PW_P0-6       = 0x20 0x20 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00
EN_AA            = 0x00
EN_RXADDR        = 0x03
RF_CH            = 0x4c
RF_SETUP         = 0x27
CONFIG           = 0x0f
DYNPD/FEATURE    = 0x00 0x00
Data Rate        = 250KBPS
Model            = nRF24L01+
CRC Length       = 16 bits
PA Power         = PA_HIGH
Now sending 23...ok...Failed, response timed out.
Now sending 1231...ok...Failed, response timed out.
Now sending 2441...ok...Failed, response timed out.
Now sending 3649...ok...Failed, response timed out.
Now sending 4859...ok...Failed, response timed out.
Now sending 6071...ok...Failed, response timed out.
```

and from other BBB pongtest
 ./pongtest

```
RF24/examples/pingpair/
ROLE: Pong back
STATUS           = 0x0e RX_DR=0 TX_DS=0 MAX_RT=0 RX_P_NO=7 TX_FULL=0
RX_ADDR_P0-1     = 0xf0f0f0f0d2 0xf0f0f0f0e1
RX_ADDR_P2-5     = 0xc3 0xc4 0xc5 0xc6
TX_ADDR          = 0xf0f0f0f0d2
RX_PW_P0-6       = 0x20 0x20 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00
EN_AA            = 0x00
EN_RXADDR        = 0x03
RF_CH            = 0x4c
RF_SETUP         = 0x27
CONFIG           = 0x0f
DYNPD/FEATURE    = 0x00 0x00
Data Rate        = 250KBPS
Model            = nRF24L01+
CRC Length       = 16 bits
PA Power         = PA_HIGH
```

Can someone help me ?

Answer (score 1):

Based on your data, both devices have a status register value of `0x0e`, which is clearing the lsb; that bit sets the direction of the device, either Tx (0) or Rx (1).  Based on the status register of each board being cleared, you have both of them setup as transmitters.